# How can I use bitcoind from the command line on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, bitcoin, bitcoind

Apparently bitcoind should be bundled with Bitcoin-QT which I have installed, but I can't find it?

Comment: Bitcoin-Qt for Linux comes with `bitcoind` pre-compiled in the `bin` directory. Where did you search for the file?

Comment: I am using OS X. I have Bitcoin-QT installed in /Applications. Tried find / -iname "bitcoind" and the os x spotlight thing